# Blank Screen after updating state in React Native Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm getting `Home` component when rendering it for the first time, but when I change the state in `componentDidMount` HomeComponent navigates HomeComponent again and then goes to a blank page. It's irrespective of `_renderScene` logic.

If I simply `return <Home>` in _renderScene, it still gives me blank screen after `componentDidMount()`

```
import { actions as navActions } from 'react-native-navigation-redux-helpers';


class HomeContainer extends Component {

  _renderScene(sceneProps) {
    return <Home />
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(navActions.jumpTo(1, "main"))
    // Works when
    // this.props.dispatch(navActions.jumpTo(1, "home")
    // Here I change the state of homeNavigation.
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationCardStack
        navigationState={this.props.homeNav}
        renderScene={this._renderScene.bind(this)}
      />
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    mainNav: state.mainNavigation,
    homeNav: state.homeNavigation
  };
}
```

It works when I change the state of homeNav `this.props.dispatch(navActions.jumpTo(1, "home"))`,
 but when I change mainNav as in the above code after rendering `<Home />` first time it then navigates  again and goes to a blank screen'.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in your code, when you dispatching action in componentDidMount() method like:

```
this.props.dispatch(navActions.jumpTo(1, "main"))
```

then your mapStateToProps() methods only receiving mainNav prop and homeNav has nil or blank value at this update. After receiving mainNav your render() method is executing and in your render you are passing homeNav which is currently nil or blank as:

```
<NavigationCardStack
        navigationState={this.props.homeNav}
        renderScene={this._renderScene.bind(this)}
      />
```

By value blank or nil its not getting redirect on your Home component and showing blank screen. You should use mainNav in this case or should pass mainNav also with homeNav. Thanks!

Comment: how to pass both navigationState as one? or meant something like nested state?

Comment: No, When you are sending state updates from your reducer then you should pass from there.

Comment: I kept a debugger in render(), I could see both homeNav and mainNav with the latest state.